# Without using row operations, and by inspection, Find one nontrivial solution to Ax=0

Tags: linear-algebra

[Link to the image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qbaj.png)

Hi, I am stuck on this problem. Can anyone explain to me how I can come to a conclusion.

Comment: $C_2 = 2C_1 + C_3$. Can you find something similar for rows ?

Comment: I would discourage you from simply linking to "the image of the problem".  Strive to make the body of your Question as self-contained as practical.  The [use of MathJax](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) and $\LaTeX$ allows posting of mathematical expressions.

Answer (score 1):

let $c_1, c_2, c_3$ be the columns $1,2,$ and $3$ of the matrix. observe that $0 = 2c_1-c_2+c_3 = \pmatrix{c_1, c_2, c_3}\pmatrix{2\\-1\\1}.$

therefore, one solution to the matrix equation $Ax = 0$ is $x = 2, y = -1, z = 1.$